# Reemplazar una cadena por otra si se encuentra después de un patrón y antes de otro

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, replace

```py
import re

input_text = "Creo que ((PERS)los viejos gabinetes) estan en desuso, hay que hacer algo con ellos, ya que ellos son importantes. ellos quedaron en el deposito."

pattern_01 = r"((PERS)\s*los\s[\w\s]+)((?:\.\s*\n|\n|\.))"
output = re.sub(pattern_01, r"\1, \1\3", input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

print(output)
```

Reemplace cualquier subcadena `"ellos"` antes del primer punto `.` después de una secuencia `((PERS)\s*los )` con el contenido dentro de esos corchetes `((PERS)\s*los )` que deben encontrarse antes de que ocurra esa subcadena `"ellos"`

Usar este código directamente no modifica la cadena

Pero necesitaría obtener esta salida:

```
"Creo que ((PERS)los viejos gabinetes) estan en desuso, hay que hacer algo con los viejos gabinetes, ya que los viejos gabinetes son importantes. ellos quedaron en el deposito."
```

Que debería cambiar en mi código para obtener esta string como salida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuantas horas y días perdidos tras la quimera de las expresiones regulares. Hay que saber usarlas combinadas con otras técnicas.

Por ejemplo, requieres que los reemplazos se hagan solo antes del primer punto. Fácil:

```
antes, despues = input_text.split('.', maxsplit=1)
```

Tengo el texto dividido y lo que me interesa es `antes` del primer punto.

Ahora usara una expresión regular simple para buscar el texto de reemplazo:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\(PERS\)\s*(los\s[\w\s]+)")
m = pattern.search(antes)
```

(De paso: hay que escapar los paréntesis en la expresión, si no se interpreta como grupo de captura)

`search()` retorna un `Match Object`, que me da una tonelada de información sobre las cosas que encontró. De eso solo me interesan los indices de inicio/termino dentro del string:

```
start = m.start(1)
end = m.end(1)
```

(Puede haber más de un match, por lo que debes indicar con cual trabajar. En este caso, el primer match es el 1.)

Esos indices me sirven para separar el string `antes` en dos partes y obtener el texto encontrado:

```
texto_encontrado = antes[start:end]
pre = antes[:end]
post= antes[end:]
```

Finalmente, aplico la sustitución sobre la parte posterior de `antes`:

```
post = re.sub("ellos", texto_encontrado, post)
```

Y construyo el reemplazo final:

```
final = pre + post + '.' + despues
```

> Advertencia: Este código no contiene chequeo de errores. El OP debe
> agregarlos según su necesidad.

#### Demo

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\(PERS\)\s*(los\s[\w\s]+)")

input_text = "Creo que ((PERS)los viejos gabinetes) estan en desuso, hay que hacer algo con ellos, ya que ellos son importantes. ellos quedaron en el deposito."
antes, despues = input_text.split('.', maxsplit=1)

m = pattern.search(antes)

start = m.start(1)
end = m.end(1)

texto_encontrado = antes[start:end]
pre = antes[:end]
post= antes[end:]
post = re.sub("ellos", texto_encontrado, post)
final = pre + post + '.' + despues
print(final)
```

produce:

```
Creo que ((PERS)los viejos gabinetes) estan en desuso, hay que hacer algo con los viejos gabinetes, ya que los viejos gabinetes son importantes. ellos quedaron en el deposito.

Process finished with exit code 0
```